# How to separate data in a Backbone model for presentation versus persistence?

Tags: backbone.js

I have a Model where some of the data returned from the server is not editable by the client but is used for display purposes. However, there is some data that is editable and should be sent to the server. How should I separate these? I feel like this involves some sort of combination of overriding `parse` and `toJSON` or maybe `save` but I'm not sure how to go about this the right way. How would you do this?

Answer (score 0):

My first reaction would be *"don't mix the view state with the model"*, it would be much better to create a specific view-model, pass your data-model into `initialize` and set the fields you need on the view-model from the data-model there.

Overriding `parse` won't do anything since it's only used when parsing responses from the server.

Overriding `toJSON` and have it return only the attributes you're interrested in sending to the server should work. If you look at the [Backbone source](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1356)

```
// Ensure that we have the appropriate request data.
if (options.data == null && model && (method === 'create' || method === 'update' || method === 'patch')) {
  params.contentType = 'application/json';
  params.data = JSON.stringify(options.attrs || model.toJSON(options));
}
```

It should be using your model's `toJSON` function as long as you didn't pass any attributes to `save`.